# Is it possible to write directly to sass partials from the dev tools?

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a local website and have added its folder as a workspace. For it I am using .sass files and _partials which compile into a css file and a sourcemap. When I am inspecting the element, the source is the correct partial. When I am adding css rules directly to the class of the element, they are immediately saved, but to the compiled file.

writing css directly to the element styles:

[image]

change is immediately saved in the compiled style.css:

[image]

Is it possible for this change to be also saved to the original sass partial? Like is there a reverse watcher for the compiled css, which can detect changes and write them to the partial from where the class rules originate?

Comment: Should work if you have a `sass --watch` running ?

Comment: @anderssonola can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: Chrome workspace can't compile your sass files. But you can have a `sass --watch` running compiling when you change your sass files. How do you compile your sass outside of chrome workspace?

Comment: I'm using Atom text editor with an extension which compiles it for me. I have no problem compiling sass to css files. I asked for the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Sass file in the Sources panel.

For example, suppose that you wanted to change the `margin:0` declaration for your `.header-general .header-title` ruleset.

[image: example]

Click `_shortcodes.sass:9` to open the file in the Sources panel. Make your edits there, and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for Mac) to save.